# Selenium RadioButton & Checkbox button values without ID or Name

Tags: selenium, checkbox, radio-button, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write and read values from radio buttons and checkboxes which id and name values are changing and not fixed. Therefore I cannot use these as identifiers.

Checkout the below image, this shows a list of radio buttons and checkboxes and the inspected element in chrome. Note that the Name and ID underlined in red are not fixed and cannot be used.

[Radio Button & Checkbox - Inspect Element from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21mCy.png)

Comment: Which of them do you want to read? Aside from You can use XPATH expressions then.

Comment: I want to read Radiobutton A & Checkbox A &C - when I copy xpath I get this = //*[@id="radio_6203_3265"] which cannot be used as id is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your id is dynamic, you can not use it. There are so many ways to find element.

```
By.xpath
By.cssselector
By.linktext
By.name
```

,....
If you want to use selenium you must know at least first two.

visit link

https://devqa.io/selenium-css-selectors/

https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: I tried using xpath however I got this result from xpath - = //*[@id="radio_6203_3265"]  which cannot be used as id is dynamic

Comment: Again your id is dynamic you can not use ID in your xpath css or whatever you cose. Try with the class name node, and then navigete to child tag, and try to get text. I will not bring solution for you, I will give you only way of thinking.Tommorow it wiil be new element and if you do not know method, than you will countiniously have issues.